# gwt dynamic number of presenter widgets

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt

Is there a way to add a dynamic number of presenter widgets? I can add individual presenters just fine but how do I add a collection. I have a placeholder in my UiBinder XML

ui.xml

```
 <g:LayoutPanel ui:field="collection"/>
```

View

```
@Override
public void setInSlot(Object slot, Widget content) {
    if (slot == TicketPresenter.DYNAMIC_COLLECTION_SLOT) {
        collection.clear();
        collection.add(content);
    } 
}
```

Presenter

```
setInSlot(DYNAMIC_COLLECTION_SLOT, collectionPresenter);
```

But I want to be able to have a List presenters and add them all to the collection panel. Is this possible? I know I can create a composite to do this but I want to use presenter widgets.

Comment: what do you mean by "presenter widget"? It would be more clear if you show what you want in pseudo code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually in your View you will override not only

```
@Override
public void setInSlot(Object slot, Widget content)
```

but also

```
@Override
public void addToSlot(Object slot, Widget content)
```

So you can iterate over your Widget collection and call addToSlot for each widget. Your addToSLot impl will look like

```
@Override
public void addToSlot(Object slot, Widget content) {
    if (slot == TicketPresenter.DYNAMIC_COLLECTION_SLOT) {
        collection.add(content);
    } 
}
```

It means that you do not need to clear your layout container on Add operation.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void addListOfWidgets(List<Widget> content) {
    collection.clear();
    for (Widget widget : content) {
        collection.add(widget);
    }
}
```